# Prefix alphabets with $ regex

Tags: python, regex, shell

I want to prefix all alphabets in a string with `$`.

Can someone tell me how to do it with regex?

Example: if `str = 'he123'`, output should be `$h$e123`.

I am a beginner to regex. I tried this but doesn't work:

```
re.sub('[a-zA-Z]+', '$'str, str)
```

Comment: Why are you rolling back my edit? It's only improving your question.

Comment: I am sorry I accidentally rolled back your edits. Please re-edit the post. I thought rolling back removes the red highlights alone.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `+` after the character class and then put the character class into a capturing group. `+` greedily matches one or more characters.

```
>>> re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])', r'$\1', 'he123')
'$h$e123'
```

OR

Use positive lookahead assertion.

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?=[a-zA-Z])', r'$', 'he123')
'$h$e123'
```

Answer (score 2):

non-regex solution:

```
''.join(['$' + c if c.isalpha() else c for c in str])
```

---

```
>>> str = 'he12th'
>>> ''.join(['$' + c if c.isalpha() else c for c in str])
'$h$e12$t$h'
```